# JavaScript: Pass new variable to default method

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, asynccallback

I'm writing a node application which uses a lot of promises.  In an effort to keep my code readable I'm removing as many anonymous functions as possible and storing them in one JavaScript object like the following.

```
let myCallbacks = {
  myFirstCallback: function(fulfill, reject) {
    // Do some stuff
    if(noError)
      fulfill({field: 'data'});
    else
      reject('ERROR');
  },
  mySecondCallback: function(fulfill, reject) {
    // Do some stuff
    if(noError)
      fulfill({field: 'data'});
    else
      reject('ERROR');
  }
}

let myFirstMethod = function() {
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.myFirstCallback);
}

let mySecondMethod = function() {
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.mySecondCallback);
}
```

This works perfect.

Now I have a function where I need to pass data to my callbacks.  Imagine the following code

```
let myCallbacks = {
  myFirstCallback: function(fulfill, reject) {
    // Do some stuff
    if(noError)
      fulfill({field: 'data'});
    else
      reject('ERROR');
  },
  mySecondCallback: function(fulfill, reject) {
    // Do some stuff
    if(noError)
      fulfill({field: 'data'});
    else
      reject('ERROR');
  },
  myThirdCallback: function(fulfill, reject, someVariable) {
    // Do some stuff
    if(someVariable*3>10)
      fulfill({field: 'data'});
    else
      reject('ERROR');
  }
}

let myFirstMethod = function() {
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.myFirstCallback);
}

let mySecondMethod = function() {
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.mySecondCallback);
}

let myThirdMethod = function(someVariable) {
  // Doesn't work
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.myThirdCallback);

  // Doesn't work
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.myThirdCallback(fulfill, reject, someVariable);

  // Doesn't work
  return new Promise(myCallbacks.myThirdCallback(someVariable));
}
```

What is the correct way to pass someVariable from myThirdMethod to myCallbacks.myThirdCallback()?

Comment: First and foremost you have some syntax errors when calling `myCallbacks.myThirdCallback`. You need to close the `new Promise` with the closing `)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you, corrected.  I just typed this out real quick as a much easier example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var thatOtherCallback = function(variable)
{
   return function(fulfill, reject)
   {
     ... use variable and do whatever you need to do ...
   }
}

...

new Promise(thatOtherCallback(value));
```

But without a clearer understanding of what you're trying to achieve, it's difficult to say whether this is a good solution.

Comment: This was perfect, I can't believe I didn't even think of it.  Thank you.